# C# - how do I schedule code to run everyday on a specific time and send email only when the row is added in a database table

Tags: c#, database, email, automation, scheduler

I write now have a code that updates and lists files from the SFTP site into a database table. Whenever there's a new file uploaded on a client SFTP site I am supposed to get an email notification. In order to do that I set a task scheduler on my local machine. Now, I get an email every day at a set time which is great but how do I only and only get an email when a new file has been uploaded on the sftp site or a new row/s has been added into a database table. I do not want to get an email every day, only email notify me when there's a new file.

Please point me in the right direction. What do I do?

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        string host = @"";
        string username = "";
        string password = @"";
     

        Dictionary<string, string[]> fileMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();


        using (SftpClient sftp = new SftpClient(host, username, password))
        {
            List<DateTime> sftpdates = new List<DateTime>();
            IEnumerable<SftpFile> files = null;
            try
            {
                sftp.Connect();
                files = sftp.ListDirectory(".");

                // Get SFTP dates 

                foreach (var file in files)

                {
                    Console.Write(file.Name + "\t");
                    Console.WriteLine(file.Attributes.LastWriteTime);
                    if (!file.Name.Equals(".") || !file.Name.Equals(".."))
                    {

                    }
                    sftpdates.Add(file.Attributes.LastWriteTime);
                }
                sftp.Disconnect();
                sftpdates.Sort();
                sftpdates.Reverse();
                Console.WriteLine("Latest " + sftpdates[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception has been caught " + e.ToString());
            }


            // get lastestfile recieved stored in a DB and Compare the dates ( greater or not ) if yes ;
            var con = new SqlConnection(@"connection string here");
            con.Open();
            {
                SqlCommand getMaxdateDB = new SqlCommand
               ("select * from LatestFile ", con);
                SqlDataReader reader = getMaxdateDB.ExecuteReader();
                DateTime DatabaseDate = new DateTime();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    DatabaseDate = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                }
                reader.Close();

                if (sftpdates[0].CompareTo(DatabaseDate) > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Newer file exists");
                }
                else if (sftpdates[0].CompareTo(DatabaseDate) == 0)

                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Latest dates are same");
                }
            }

            // if yes // send new records to db 
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    SqlCommand getFile = new SqlCommand(
                            "select FILE_NAME, date_modified from NewFileUpload where File_Name='"
                            + file.Name + "';", con);
                    SqlDataReader readfile = getFile.ExecuteReader();
                    bool row = readfile.HasRows;
                    string fileName;
                    DateTime date_modified = new DateTime();
                    try
                    {
                        fileName = readfile.GetString(0);
                        date_modified = readfile.GetDateTime(1);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                    readfile.Close();
                    if (row == false)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("New file added...");
                        DateTime myDateTime = file.Attributes.LastWriteTime;
                        string sqlFormattedDate = myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
                        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("insert into NewFileUpload(File_Name, File_Size, Date_Modified) values " +
                    "('" + file.Name + "', '" + file.Attributes.Size + "', '" + sqlFormattedDate + "')", con);
                        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        fileMetadata.Add(file.Name, new string[] { file.Attributes.Size.ToString(), sqlFormattedDate });

                    }
                }
                // send email
                // EMAIL LOGIC
                SendEmailMultiFiles(fileMetadata);

                {
                    SqlCommand UpdateLatestDate = new SqlCommand
                        ("truncate table LatestFile", con);
                    UpdateLatestDate.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    UpdateLatestDate = new SqlCommand
                   ("INSERT INTO LatestFile select max(Date_Modified) from NewFileUpload where File_Name not in ('..' ,'.')", con);
                    UpdateLatestDate.ExecuteNonQuery()


                }
            }


        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void SendEmail(string filename, long filesize, DateTime datemodified)


    {

        //List <> NewUploadList = List  <> NewUploadList = new List<>(); /// might only send the date or file name
        // Key = filename
        // value = [filesize(string), datemodified/lastwrite(string)]
        Dictionary<string, string[]> fileMetadata = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    }

    static void SendEmailMultiFiles(Dictionary<string, string[]> fileMetadata
   

        //List <> NewUploadList = List  <> NewUploadList = new List<>(); /// might only send the date or file name
        Console.WriteLine("Email has been sent.");
        string SendMailbody = "File(s) added<br>";
        //+ filename + " file size: "
        //+ filesize + " date modified: "
        //+ datemodified;
        int i = 1;
        foreach (var item in fileMetadata)
        {
            SendMailbody += i++ + ") " + item.Key + " file size: "
                + item.Value[0] + " date modified: "
                + item.Value[1] + "<br>";
        }

        string mailto = "";
        string mailfrom = "";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(mailfrom);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     
        mail.Subject = "New File Incoming";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = SendMailbody;
        smtp.Send(mail);



    }
}
```

}

Comment: Look into Windows task scheduler. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page

Comment: I have done that, it send me email everyday whether or not there has been changes in SFTP site or my database table

Comment: btw, your posted code contains login credentials - I recommend removing those and changing the password  that got exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the fileMetadata object before sending to the function.

```
If (fileMetadata.Count >= 1)
{
    SendEmailMultiFiles(fileMetadata);
}
```

Comment: You are adding new files to the dictionary "fileMetadata", so that code checks if there are any records in the dictionary before calling your code that is responsible for sending the email.